# SKSpritekit Load Image Memory Error

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am loading a 500kb background image to SKSpriteNode, however when I run in the device, it shows Message from debugger: Terminated due to Memory Error.

I run it on simulator, I can see that when load the image, the memory consumption is 700MB which takes 1 second, after this 1 second memory consumption remains 40MB. Here is how I load this background image to SKSpriteNode. I am pretty sure that the file size of this image is only 500kb.

HelloScene.m

```
-(SKSpriteNode*) node {
SKSpriteNode* node = [SKSpriteNode node];
node = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"test_full.png"];
node.position=CGPointMake(150, 100);
node.size= CGSizeMake(100, 100);
node.zPosition=0;
return node;
}
- (void)createSceneContents
{
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFit;
self.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
[self addChild:[self node]];

}
```

ViewController.m

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{
[super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
SKView *spriteView = (SKView *) self.view;
spriteView.showsDrawCount = YES;
spriteView.showsNodeCount = YES;
spriteView.showsFPS = YES;
HelloScene* hello = [HelloScene sceneWithSize:spriteView.bounds.size];
hello.scaleMode=SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

[spriteView presentScene: hello];

}
```

Need some help
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `test_full.png` file and the size of the file is 500kb. But it is **PNG** file. The file size 500kb is not help to understand the issue.

SpriteKit cannot use PNG file directly for rendering. It uses OpenGL ES APIs and raw RGBA 32bit image data (from PNG file, basically). Under the hood, SpriteKit uses UIImage(or similar framework) to decode image files for getting raw image data. So the important point is, how large pixels is the image file. The amount of memory to store the image equals to WIDTH x HEIGHT x 4 bytes.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. The dimension of the image is 25000*4167.  What if I want to use a large picture, any suggestions? what format should I use? Can I use svg format or pdf format in SpriteKit? Thanks

Comment: 25000*4167!? It requires about 400MB. I think it's almost impossible to use on iOS devices. I recommend you to create another question. Don't forget to accept this answer :)

Comment: It is most definitely impossible because there's a max texture size which is 4096x4096 on most devices. You can't load images any larger than that.

Comment: You simply cannot use images that large, since all possible memory will be consumed to hold the decompressed image data in memory. Use smaller images or resize them on a server and then provide the smaller image data to the embedded device.